# Numerical outputs of experiments which gives spectrum of blackbody

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, experimental-physics, thermal-radiation

Many books have spectrum of blackbody radiation in some temperatures before result of Planck and say this is result of experiment. But they don't have any table as result of measurements from them we obtain smooth curve of spectrum. I need experimental numbers which give spectrum for a specific temperature say $T=1500 K$: spectral radiancy as a function of frequency. I don't found such a thing on internet and my books and need it because it is one of the main substances for Planck to solve the problem.

Comment: See the paper by van Dongen "In Europe", Fig. 7. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/339664052_In_Europe/fulltext/5e8ee2334585150839cada22/In-Europe.pdf

Comment: Please do not delete and repost a nearly-identical question. Questions can be *edited*.